# Special values of $\sum_{n\ge1}z^n/(n^2\binom{2n}{n})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

Consider the series
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac{z^n}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}$$
which converges for $|z|\le4$.

One has $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=\pi^2/18$, $f(2)=\pi^2/8$, $f(3)=2\pi^2/9$, and $f(4)=\pi^2/2$.
Naive question: are there any other reasonably "explicit" evaluations (for instance for
$z=-1$, $-2$, $1/2$...) ? Note that the series for $z=1$ is related to Ap'ery's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(2)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I interpret the request of the OP for an "explicit" evaluation of the series as a request for a "closed-form" expression, which exists (it seems to go back to Euler, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/383181/87355) are several proofs):
$$f(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\dfrac{z^n}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}=2 \arcsin^2\,(\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{z}),\;\;|z|\leq 4.$$

Comment: The identity is also stated in the Wikipedia page on inverse trigonometric functions ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#cite_ref-Borwein_2004_20-0 ). A reference is given to the book "Experimentation in Mathematics: Computational Paths to Discovery" (1 ed.) by Borwein, Bailey and Gingersohn. A proof via hypergeometric functions is sketched on page 51 of that book.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my naivete, I probably knew this formula. Apologies.